# How can a webserver run unprivileged but do root things?

Tags: security, webserver, root

I have an server application exposes basic system and network information for the host computer, behind authentication. I would like to expand the server to be able to expose information about sensors, tasks requiring direct adapter access, and other low-level things.

Here is the problem: the things I would like to add require root access. To my knowledge, it is generally considered bad practice to run a webserver as root because an authentication issue or server bug would mean the entire system is compromised, as opposed to only whatever the server user has access to. What is a reasonable way to allow access to these root-level things while keeping an appropriate level of security?

My initial thought is to create two separate daemons that communicate via a socket or other IPC, one running the web backend as a standard user and one running as root. These could share a binary for easier distribution.

The design would mean an attacker must compromise two levels to gain root (user-webserver and root-daemon IPC/validation) as opposed to only needing to find an exploit in a root-webserver. But this seems like significant added complexity for somewhat debatable gain (given that dedicated hardware is likely the only way to provide "complete" isolation).

What do similar programs do to meet these requirements?

Answer (score 1):

In short, you're right. Don't run a webserver as root. Segregating the processes is definitely the right idea.

I see things like this more in distributed systems, so communications of this sort would likely be over gRPC. Monitoring and administration tasks usually aren't exposed through a local webserver at all, but rather a separate agent altogether. There might be a web interface you use to administer a server and perform low-level tasks -- but it would be running on another machine entirely.

It's helpful to understand how this looks from the attacker's point of view to understand why. The  majority of attackers are using common, off-the-shelf tools that scan for known vulnerabilities. They are not investigating your application manually. Scans like this happen all the time on public-facing websites, and there aren't reliable ways to prevent them. The actual exploitation step is likely also going to use an off-the-shelf tool.

At this point, if they have root access, they're done - and what I've just described a trivial amount of effort.

Once an attacker has to actually start analyzing an web application manually, the level of effort goes up greatly. Just like with home security, part of the goal is to make the level of effort required to break in greater than the potential rewards of doing so.

There could be some other considerations as well. In particular, it isn't a great idea to send commands for the root daemon to run as strings -- that could easily lead to command injection. In other words, an attacker could likely find a way to influence the content of those strings to force the root daemon to execute arbitrary commands.

Comment: Awesome response, thank you. When using gRPC, do these dedicated machines then have their RPC daemons run as root? Also, any chance you know of any open source software that does something like this?